# Cannot control audio volume in Safari when using createMediaElementSource()

Tags: safari, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have an html audio player and I use it with createMediaElementSource() to make a visualizer. But I can't change the volume for it from Safari. When I change the volume to 0 it logs it correctly (0) in the console, but the actual volume is still at 1. It works in other browsers.

```
const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || 
window.webkitAudioContext
var audio = new AudioContext()
var $audioPlayer = document.querySelector('.player-element__player')
var analyser = audio.createAnalyser()
analyser.fftSize = 32
analyser.connect(audio.destination)
var source = audio.createMediaElementSource($audioPlayer)
source.connect(analyser)
$audioPlayer.volume = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the solution for now is to make a GainNode and control the volume from there.